# Trying to add basic rich text support via html to a jface tableviewer?

Tags: java, html, eclipse-rcp, jface

So I'm trying to add basic rich text support to a jface tableviwer such as bold, underline, italic and highlight and also need to be able to save this to a model so I though a nice way would be to use a subset of html (or xml) tags. However I can't seem find a way render html in the tableviewer. I've looked at the StyledCellLabelProvier but its styledranges seem to only support foreground and background color and not font and type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't render HTML in a table viewer, because that would require rendering HTML in an SWT `Table`, and *that* would require native HTML rendering in tables on all supported platforms and window systems.

Comment: Ok I see, but I only need to support a sub set of platforms and I know the SWT browser widget definitely work on these platforms surely I implement extend the table class?

Comment: @dead_zero The thing is, `Table` class itself does very little work. All rendering is done by native controls: Win32 table, Cocoa table, Gnome table, etc. And you can't extend them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at all public fields of `StyleRange`. There's a lot more than foreground and background color. Hint: They're inherited from `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextStyle`.

Comment: Thanks for the input been looking into this setting the foreground and background color works like a charm but the font styles don't. I can set the entire cell contents to bold via `cell.setFont(boldFont)` but if I trying similar on a range it just ignore the bold bit i.e. StyleRange(0, 4, null, colorYellow, SWT.BOLD) little bit stumped (both windows 7 and os x).

Comment: `Note: the font style is not used if the font attribute is set` Have you tried setting the font (not fontStyle) on the `StyleRange`?

Answer (score 1):

The `TextLayout` class that is called by `StyledCellLabelProvider` to draw the text doesn't use `StyleRange` but its superclass `TextStyle`. `fontStyle` is not an attribute of `TextStyle`, so it's ignored. Set the `TextStyle.font` explicitly.